# How to fix "segmentation fault (core dumped)" dependant on size

Tags: c++11

I created a class "config" that contains 12 bool values, organized in a std::array. The class has an "icing" function that returns a double value. 
Trying to order a vector of 2^12 (4096) configs through a std:: sort (contained in #include ) using a predicate i have written, i get a segmentation fault error.

Shrinking the vector to 205 (not 1 more) eliminates the error, but I don't know why. 
If i make the vector 4096 long, and try to sort only a little part, it works until the part is long 175+. 
Shrinking the vector to for example around 1000, limits the partial sorting to around 20, before it gives the segmentation error.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class config {
public: 
    config (){       //constructor, default
        array<bool,12> t;
        for (bool& b: t){
            b=false;
        }
        val=t;
        g=1;
    }
    config (const config& fro): val(fro.val){};   //copy constructor
    array<bool,12> get_val(){ return val; }  //returns the array
    void set_tf(int n, bool tf){ val[n]=tf; }  //sets a certain boolean     in the array to false/true
    void set_g(double d){ g=d; }  //this sets the constant for     calculation to a number
    void print(){
        cout<<"values: ";
        for (auto b: val){ cout<<b<<" "; }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    config & incr(int n=1){ //this increases the vector by 1 following the rules for binary numbers, but has the digits reversed
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int i=0;
            bool out=false;
            while(val[i]==true){
                val[i]=false;
                i++;
            }
            val[i]=true;
        }
        return *this;
    }   
    double energy(){
        int ct=0;
        int cf=0;
        for(auto b:val){ if(b==true){ ct++; } else { cf++; } }
        return (abs(ct-cf));
    }
    double icing(){        //here is the "value" for ordering purposes
        int n=0;
        for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
            if(val[i]!=val[i+1]){ n++; }
        }
        double temp=-g*n+this->energy();
        return temp;
    }
private:
    array<bool,12> val;
    double g;
};

bool pred (config c1, config c2){ return c1.icing()>c2.icing(); }     //this sets the ordering predicate

template <typename T>    //this orders the vector
void csort (vector <T>& in){
    sort(in.begin(), in.end(), pred);
}

int main(){
    vector<config> v;
    for (int i=0; i<4096; i++){ //cicle that creates a vector of successive binaries
        for(auto& c:v){
            c.incr();
        }
        config t;
        v.push_back(t);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.begin()+174, pred);   //this gives seg.fault when 175+
    csort(v);           //this gives segmentation fault when the vec is 206 long or longer
}
```

I expected the code to order the vector, but it goes into segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behaviour in `sort` function because your predicate takes `config` by value, so copies are made and in this place copy constructor is called which copies only array `val`, but not `g`.

```
bool pred (config c1, config c2){ return c1.icing()>c2.icing(); } 
//         takes by value, copy ctor is called 
config (const config& fro): val(fro.val){}; // only val is copied, g HAS GARBAGE VALUE
// icing in pred uses g !! - stric weak ordering is violated because g has GARBAGE VALUE
```

Fix 1:
pass config by `const config&`:

```
bool pred (const config& c1, const config& c2){ return c1.icing()>c2.icing(); }
```

or fix 2:
`g` is initialized in copy constructor:

```
config (const config& fro): val(fro.val), g(fro.g){};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with the second approach, bc the first one gives problems because the icing function is not defined as const, so it starts spitting out the "disregards qualifiers [f-permissive] error". 
The second approach is a good catch, thanks! 
The thing is, the class was to be ordered by energy first, then had some modifications which led to the addition of the g private value, and the relative term. When doing so, i forgot to add g into the copy constructor and only added it to the constructor... :/ silly me